# how to auto-indent latex in sublime text 4?

Tags: latex, auto-indent, sublimetext4

The sublime text auto-indent (ctrl+shift+p "indentation: Reindent Lines") doesn't work for latex files.  I suspect sublime-text doesn't recognize/associate a particular set of indentation rules for .tex files (works fine for python).

I also haven't been able to find anything which auto-indents in the [LatexTools](https://latextools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) plugin.  [This old-ish (2014) question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164645/indenting-style-of-latex-files-with-sublime-text) doesn't seem to work for me as well.

(running sublime text 4 on ubuntu 22.04 if relevant)

Comment: Maybe you could use https://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexindent instead?

Comment: looks promising @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, I'll give it a shot now (will update with some sublime text integration below if I get it working)

Answer (score 3):

Per @samcarter's answer above, installing the perl script [ctan.org/pkg/latexindent](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexindent) indents as needed.

I wanted to integrate a bit with sublime-text so I wrote a little plugin ([largely stolen from here](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/run-command-after-saving-file/44016)).  To install yourself, just make a new plugin (Tools > Developer > New Plugin ...) and past the code below as `latexindent.py` (sublime should default to the proper location for this file if you created it via the tools menu as described).

```py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin
import os
import subprocess

class LatexIndentOnSave(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_post_save_async(self, view):
        filename = view.file_name()    
        if filename.endswith('.tex'):
            subprocess.run(['latexindent', filename, '-o', filename], cwd=os.path.dirname(filename))
```

Note that this plugin will run `latexindent` on all files ending in .tex after saving them, replacing the original contents (which can be very troublesome if latexindent isn't working as you'd like!).  If you'd like to have a backup made with every save, consider swapping the `-o` for the `-w` switch as @cmhughes suggests below.

Comment: Nicely done :) just for reference, using the -o switch like this circumvents the backup routine, so perhaps consider using the -w switch...? (cmhughes, author of latexindent)

Comment: Hi @cmhughes, thanks for the suggestion (and for latexindent, works great!)  I kind of like the -o switch to the -w as all the backup files can pile up in my directory and make it a bit messier.  Even so, this is just my preference, I'll add a bit more to the solution above to clarify this for everybody else.

Comment: No worries, you're not alone in discovering and preferring it :) but, I'll note here that I don't recommend it, and instead recommend tweaking the back up routine (many options) . But, everyone should do as they wish!